# When tried to copy from PDF generated with LaTeX, I got garbled code instead

Tags: copy-paste

[image]So I was trying to copy text from PDF files generated from XeLaTeX, but for whatever reason, it results in garbled sign.
But it does work when opened through the built in pdf viewer in TeXShop
Also, the CHinese character is perfectly copyable, only the English version is not.